# How to retrieve a field value from a form using Aspose PDF in Java?

Tags: pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

So I'm using this code to get field names and their values from a PDF file.

```
Document doc = new Document("path\\to\\file\\Sample.pdf");
Field[] fields = doc.getForm().getFields();
for (Field f : fields)  {
    System.out.println(f.getFullName() + " : " + f.getValue());
}
```

Let's say I've the following fields in the form and the above code displays these fields as:

```
First Name    : John 
Middle Name   :
Last Name     : Doe
Suffix        : Jr
Date of Birth : 01-01-1985
Nationality   : American
```

**How can I just print certain required field(s)?**

Like if I want to print only the `Last Name` and `Date of Birth` using Aspose PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate among fields with their `FullName`. Certain fields can be printed if you enclose the `println` method in an `if` condition, as in the code below:

```
if ((f.getFullName().contains("Last Name")) || (f.getFullName().contains("Date of Birth")))  {
System.out.println(f.getFullName() + " : " + f.getValue());
}
```

I hope this will be helpful. Please feel free to contact us if you need any further assistance.

*I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.*

Comment: How to get a value from a radio button (RadioButtonField)?

Comment: Would you please share a sample document while mentioning what value do you want to get from a RadioButtonField. Kindly upload it to Google Drive, Dropbox etc. and share the link with us.

Comment: Can you please answer the question, you can make one sample by yourself as well.